# Cannot delete older kernels - boot partition full

Tags: updates

My **boot partition** is full and I am unable to delete old kernels.  The rest of my partions have plenty of free space.  Can this be the reason that I am unable to install updates or additional software packages?  Please see everything that I've tried so far:

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                     472M  464M     0 100% /boot
...
```

Determine kernel version:

**uname -r**

```
4.8.0-37-generic
```

Determine distribution version number:

**lsb_release -sr**

```
16.10
```

List installed kernels:

**dpkg --list | grep linux-image**

```
ii  linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic  4.8.0-22.24  amd64   Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic  4.8.0-22.24  amd64  Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

**Note**: Many more items are listed than just the above.

Attempt to delete the listed kernel:

**apt-get purge linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-49-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-49-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-49-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**apt autoremove**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic but it is not installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic but it is not installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic but it is not installed
linux-image-extra-4.8.0-49-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-49-generic but it is not installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.8.0-49-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Note: I have tried the following several times with similar dependency errors:

**apt-get -f install**

**UPDATE**

Due to my use of **disk encryption**, I have run into this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093 which is probably something trivial for experienced linux users but not for newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove header and image like this:

```
apt-get purge linux-headers-x.x.x-xx  linux-image-x.x.x-xx
```

For example in your case:

```
apt-get purge linux-headers-4.8.0-22  linux-image-4.8.0-22
```

If apt still fails to remove the packages, you can use

```
dpkg --purge --force-all linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-22 linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic
```

After that:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as follows: apt-get purge linux-headers-4.8.0-22  linux-image-4.8.0-22 but it still fails and reports dependency issues.

Comment: Probably won't work as written when df is 100%. Easy to fix: change apt to dpkg for the first removal, freeing space for apt to do the rest.

Comment: Answer ignores that the header and kernel metapackages are still pointing to the wrong versions, which will continue to cause dependency errors. Easy to fix: apt clean those two metapackages, then tell apt to --reinstall them, forcing apt to download fresh versions.

Comment: @user535733, can you provide more info, I've been stuck on my PC for two days trying to make /boot/ space.  Thank you.  I'm pretty new to Linux unfortunately.

Comment: Consider adding to this answer that 'purge' and 'remove' do exactly the same thing (none of these packages have files in /etc). People get confused by the difference unneccessarily.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran, I wrote the answer in detail long ago: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels . Sorry that others have obfuscated it....

Comment: @user535733, that article is very detailed and I do have an encrypted partition, so the boot partition is very small.  I think that what I will do is buy a new HD and not install encryption since I don't have the level of Linux knowledge to comfortably handle the extra complexities introduced.  I've been using encryption for about 6 months and this just started a couple of days ago.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran...or simply backup your data and reinstall on your existing HD. There are other (answered) questions here on how to permanently decrypt.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran It works fine with a larger boot partition, if you call autoremove after a kernel upgrade, there will be no problem on an encrypted system. It should remove old kernels automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your problems are caused by the full boot partition.  There are lots of answers on this site dealing with this issue, or having manually deleted a kernel to make room, thereby breaking the package manager.

Do you really need a separate boot partition?  You do if your disk is larger than the firmware can address at boot time, and you want to force the kernels to the beginning of the disk so they may be loaded, or if your root is encrypted, or if you are running raid.

If you decide you really don't need a separate /boot, and your root has plenty of room, try moving everything off /boot partition and into the root directory /boot.  Unmount the /boot, and remount it under /mnt.  Then copy from the /mnt/xxx to /boot .  Comment out the /etc/fstab line which mounts /boot.  Then try the fixes you've found, now that you have room to work with.